# How can I add a Bootstrap class to a 'Button' element through javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a button with the Bootstrap class = "btn btn-info" through javascript, but instead of creating a styled Button, it just creates a plain HTML button.

Code

```
let diva = document.createElement('div');
    diva.class = 'fluid-container';
    
    let newContent = document.createElement('textarea');
    newContent.id = 'content';
    newContent.class = 'form-control';
    newContent.rows = '2';
    newContent.style = 'min-width : 100%';
    newContent.placeholder = 'Add argument infavor';
    
    //button = <button class="btn btn-info col-5" type="button" id="against"><b>Against</b></button>
    let btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.type = 'submit';
    btn.class = 'btn btn-info';
    btn.innerHTML = "Submit";

    diva.appendChild(newContent);
    diva.appendChild(btn);

    parent = document.getElementById("addingArgumentArea");
    parent.appendChild(diva);
```

I am trying to use btn.class but it's not working. Why is this not working because the same method worked for the textfield created above and what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why does it work in the case of TextField, but the correct way to define the class using JavaScript DOM is to either use `classList` or use `className`, these are two DOM properties.

In your case, you should use this to add `btn btn-info` class to the button.

```js
btn.className = 'btn btn-info';
```

Or alternatively, you can also use this to add multiple classes one by one-

```js
btn.classList.add('btn');
btn.classList.add('btn-info');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) as

```
btn.classList.add('btn', 'btn-info');
```

```js
let diva = document.createElement('div');
diva.class = 'fluid-container';

let newContent = document.createElement('textarea');
newContent.id = 'content';
newContent.classList.add('form-control');
newContent.rows = '2';
newContent.style = 'min-width : 100%';
newContent.placeholder = 'Add argument infavor';

//button = <button class="btn btn-info col-5" type="button" id="against"><b>Against</b></button>
let btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.type = 'submit';
btn.classList.add('btn', 'btn-info');
btn.innerHTML = "Submit";

diva.appendChild(newContent);
diva.appendChild(btn);

parent = document.getElementById("addingArgumentArea");
parent.appendChild(diva);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="addingArgumentArea"></div>
```